# What is Ubuntu One?

Tags: cloud, ubuntu-one, storage

are there any paid subscriptions available for Ubuntu One?

What additional features does it have?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ubuntu One is an online file hosting service. It offers 2GB of space free with an option to upgrade to 50GB of storage for $10 a month.

With the **Free Version** you can:

- Sync up to 2 GB of files, contacts,
  notes, bookmarks, purchased music,
  and Gwibber broadcast messages
- Automatically sync your digital life
  to your personal cloud and with all
  of your computers Mobile Contacts
  Sync
- Mark any directory in your home
  folder for sync
- Share folders with trusted contacts
  or publish files to the Internet with
  convenient short URLs
- Sync purchased songs from the Ubuntu
  One Music Store
- Integrated with your Ubuntu computer
- Convenient web browser access to your
  personal cloud

With the **Paid Version** you get:

- 50 GB total of storage to sync more
  of your digital life
- Keep your address book updated when
  you're on the move with  Mobile
  Contacts Sync
- Mobile sync supports
  thousands of phones including
  smartphones like iPhone and Android
- Synchronize your contacts with more
  applications (like Thunderbird) and
  operating systems (Windows and OS X)